# XMLSerializer in C# not including all attributes of a Class

Tags: c#, xml

Hello I have this two classes that I want to serialize using the XMLSerializer in C#:

**Paquete.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[XmlRoot("Paquete")]
public class Paquete {

    //El identificador del paquete. Aqui ira la accion que se esta enviando en el juego 
    public enum Identificador
    {
        moverIzquierda,
        moverDerecha,
        moverArriba,
        moverAbajo,
        avanzar,
        disparar,
        Null
    }
    public Identificador identificadorPaquete;
    public int jugador; 

    //[XmlArray("B"),XmlArrayItem("Bullet")]
    public List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet> ();






    // Default Constructor
    public Paquete()
    {
        this.identificadorPaquete = Identificador.Null;
        this.jugador = -1;
        this.bullets = new List<Bullet> ();
    }


    // Convierte un paquete a un data stream para enviar y recibir datos
    //Tambien lo debemos modificar para que se acople a las acciones del juego
    public string GetDataStream()
    {
        string result = "";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Paquete));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter ();
        serializer.Serialize (writer, this);
        result = writer.ToString ();
        Debug.Log ("El xml: "+result);
        return result;


    }

}
```

**Bullet.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public class Bullet  {

    //[XmlAttribute("id")]
    int id;
    //[XmlAttribute("px")]
    float px;
    //[XmlAttribute("py")]
    float py;
    //[XmlAttribute("pz")]
    float pz;
    //[XmlAttribute("rx")]
    float rx;
    //[XmlAttribute("ry")]
    float ry;
    //[XmlAttribute("rz")]
    float rz;

    public Bullet(){
        this.px = 0;
        this.py = 0;
        this.pz = 0;
        this.rx = 0;
        this.ry = 0;
        this.rz = 0;    
    }
    public Bullet(int id,float px,float py, float pz,float rx,float ry,float rz){
        this.id = id;
        this.px = px;
        this.py = py;
        this.pz = pz;
        this.rx = rx;
        this.ry = ry;
        this.rz = rz;
    }


}
```

This is what I´m using to test my code:

```
Paquete p = new Paquete ();
p.jugador = 6;
string s;
p.bullets.Add (new Bullet(0,1,1,1,1,1,1));
p.bullets.Add (new Bullet (1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2));

s = p.GetDataStream ();
```

and the xml I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Paquete xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <identificadorPaquete>Null</identificadorPaquete>
  <jugador>6</jugador>
  <bullets>
    <Bullet />
    <Bullet />
  </bullets>
</Paquete>
```

As you can see, the Bullet array does not contain any of the attributes I defined in my class.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to make the fields public (or better yet use public properties).  `XmlSerializer` only serializes public fields and properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlSerializer doesn't take the private fields into account that's why they don't appaer in the output. If you make those variables public and mark them with XmlAttribute you can see them in the result XML:

If you change it like this

```
[XmlAttribute("id")]
public int id;
```

you'd get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Paquete xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <identificadorPaquete>Null</identificadorPaquete>
  <jugador>6</jugador>
  <bullets>
    <Bullet id="0" />
    <Bullet id="1" />
  </bullets>
</Paquete>
```